# Can't get array to copy with written copy() method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So the premise of this code is to build apon it as we learn different things like nodes and such through out the semester.

Currently, in this version of the code, I need to replace anything that uses 0 to signify the end of the collection of numbers. So let's say if array A has [1,2,5,4,0], 0 would be the indicator that we are at the end of the array.

Now in this version, we have to use a counter(a.k.a howmany in this code) to signify the end of the collection of numbers.

Currently, with this code, I'm getting out of bounds errors and I'm not fully understanding why. I'm getting it in the copy()method and also the omit() method.

Here is the main class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Intcoll2client {

    public static final int SENTINEL = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int value;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Intcoll2 P = new Intcoll2(), N = new Intcoll2(), L = new Intcoll2(5);

    System.out.println("Enter an integer to be inserted or 0 to quit:");
    value = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (value != SENTINEL) {
        if (value > 0) {
            P.insert(value);
            L.insert(value);
        } else {
            N.insert(-value);
            L.omit(-value);
        }
//            L.arraySize();
        System.out.println("Enter next integer to be inserted or 0 to quit:");
        value = keyboard.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("\nThe values in collection P are:");
    P.print();
    System.out.println("\nThe values in collection N are:");
    N.print();
    System.out.println("\nThe values in collection L are:");
    L.print();
    if (P.equals(N)) {
        System.out.println("\nP and N are equal.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nP and N are NOT equal.");
    }
    Intcoll2 A = new Intcoll2();
    A.copy(L);
    System.out.println("\nThe values in the copy of L are:\n");
    A.print();
    }
}
```

Here is the class with all of the methods I'm working with:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Intcoll2 {

private int[] c;
private int howmany;

/**
 * Creates a new array c with the size 500
 */
public Intcoll2() {
    c = new int[500];
    howmany = 0;
}

/**
 * Creates a new array with the size i
 *
 * @param i positive integer
 */
public Intcoll2(int i) {
    c = new int[i];
    howmany = 0;
}

/**
 * Pre-condition: Takes in an object of Intcoll2 Post-condition: If obj does
 * not equal c, create a new array and copy all elements from c to obj
 *
 * @param obj
 */
public void copy(Intcoll2 obj) {
    if (this != obj) {
        c = new int[obj.c.length];
        int j = 0;
        while (obj.c[j] != 0) {
            c[j] = obj.c[j];
            j++;
        }
        c[j] = 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Pre-condition: Take in positive integer i 
 * Post-condition: Return true if
 * i is greater than 0 and i is equal to element in array. Otherwise, false
 *
 * @param i positive integer
 * @return
 */
public boolean belongs(int i) {
    int j = 0;
    while ((c[j] != 0) && (c[j] != i)) {
        j++;
    }
    return ((i > 0) && (c[j] == i));
}

/**
 * Pre-condition: Take in a positive integer i 
 * Post-condition: If i is greater than 0 and is not in the current collection, insert 
 * into collection. Otherwise, do nothing. If current array is too small to
 * insert new integer, create new array double the size and copy all
 * elements into new array. Redirect new array to old reference variable.
 *
 * @param i positive integer to insert in object
 */
public void insert(int i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        int j = 0;
        while ((j < howmany) && (c[j] != 0)) {
            j++;
        }
        if (j == howmany) {
            if (j == c.length) {
                int[] newC = new int[c.length * 2];
                for (int index = 0; index < c.length; index++) {
                    newC[index] = c[index];
                }
                c = newC;
            }
            c[j] = i;
            howmany++;
        }
    }
}

public void arraySize(){
    int size = c.length;
    System.out.println("Howmany: " + howmany);
    System.out.println("Size of L: " + size);
}

/**
 * if i is greater than 0, then scan array. If i is found in the array, take
 * away and move any element after the index to fill in the 0 space
 *
 * @param i positive integer
 */

    public void omit(int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            int j = 0;
            while ((c[j] != 0) && (c[j] != i)) {
                j++;
            }
            if (c[j] == i) {
            int k = j + 1;
            while (c[k] != 0) {
                k++;
            }
            c[j] = c[k - 1];
            c[k - 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}

/**
     * Returns number of integers in a collection until loop hits 0
     *
     * @return howmany
     */
    public int get_howmany() {
        return howmany;
    }

    /**
     * Prints out the entire collection until it reaches an element of 0
     */
    public void print() {
        int j = 0;
        System.out.println();
        while (j < howmany) {
            System.out.println(c[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Pre-condition: Takes in an existing object of Intcoll1 Post-condition:
     * Compares two objects, if both collections are equal, return true.
     * Otherwise, false.
     *    
     * @param obj object containing an array
     * @return result
     */
    public boolean equals(Intcoll2 obj) {
        int j = 0;
        boolean result = true;
        while ((c[j] != 0) && result) {
            result = obj.belongs(c[j]);
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        while ((obj.c[j] != 0) && result) {
            result = belongs(obj.c[j]);
            j++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Any type of input or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please post full error message, if possible indicating the relevant line numbers somehow in the code (comment). Also seing some example input would help. For example to know if you entered 500 numbers or you can reproduce it with just 2-3 numbers as well?

Comment: Does the array c always contain a zero? Otherwise these (c[j] != 0) checks will cause your code to throw that exception.

Comment: @Gavriel So the OutOfBounds errors are: 

1. After I enter in a negative number to use omit():
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
     at Intcoll2.omit(Intcoll2.java:121)
     at Intcoll2client.main(Intcoll2client.java:27)
    Java Result: 1

And the second is when I utilize copy at the end:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
     at Intcoll2.copy(Intcoll2.java:41)
     at Intcoll2client.main(Intcoll2client.java:46)
    Java Result: 1

Comment: @RyanRoss, no need to comment twice the same UNREADABLE message. Please edit the question and add it there